# issue with z-index and dropdown menu IE11

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have an issue with my dropdown menu. I have a table and at the end of each row i have a dropdown menu like that : 
[image: table with dropdown menu]
When i hover the menu on every browser i got this : 
[image: hover dropdown]
Except on IE11 : 
[image]
Here is my CSS :

```
#dropdown_classe {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#dropdown_classe .wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#dropdown_classe .parent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
    color: #282D31;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: border-radius .1s linear, background .1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
    text-align: center;
}

#dropdown_classe .parent:hover,
#dropdown_classe .content:hover ~ .parent {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}

#dropdown_classe .content:hover ~ .parent {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#dropdown_classe .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#dropdown_classe .wrapper:hover .content {
    height: 253px;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}

#dropdown_classe .content:hover {
    height: 253px;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}


#dropdown_classe .content ul {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#dropdown_classe .content ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#dropdown_classe .content li:hover {
    background: #eee;
    color: #333;
}

#dropdown_classe .content li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    color: #888;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#dropdown_classe .content li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

If you have any advice please let me know

Ctbs1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue with this :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```